# in c# capture the screen select with out any controls in main program

Tags: c#, controls, screen, capture

Hi i have create a program capture the select area

when the program start it's make the form top most so always it's top for other program , also i transparent the form this help to capture the select area with out capture the form , i have some controls like **button** this i want to see always when make the capture

here what code i use transparent and make top most

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = (1000/30);
    timer1.Start();
    TransparencyKey = Color.LightBlue;
    BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    DoubleBuffered = true;
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

    TopMost = true;
}
```

you can select the area you want by drag or size the form i draw a rectangle
for border

i use timer so when run the program start to capture until user close the program

the problem its capture also the controls like the **button** i have in center

this i want to hide , i found solution to hide before make the capture 
and show again this work well but it's make flashing all the controls and this make pain in eyes here example when make capture

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Opacity   = 0.0;                                // hide form
    var image = CaptureDesktopSize(Cam);            // capture 
    pictureBox1.Image = image; 
    image.Save(@"C:/data/V.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    Opacity = 1.0;                                  // show form
}
```

there is any way to do this to hide the controls i don't want

i working with C#

thank you very much this my first question :) i am new user

here also one screenshot to see what i mean

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWU3U.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Also please take the tour and read about how to ask good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for reply i see this

Comment: pleasure.. @Laz